# Rewrite Engine to redirect to PHP file

Tags: php

Good Day,

I have a url that needs to be accessed as such: I am using httpd

```
site.com/username
```

should actually redirect to a PHP script with just the username data. Then, i want to be able to do a header to actually redirect in the script.

Basically, I need a way to go from username -> script that I make.

Comment: Can you please provide more input?

Comment: what you tried for it. can you please show it?

Comment: Have you looked at mod_rewrite?  Is there a reason you can't use it?

Answer (score 0):

redirect to index.php file and put your logic there

```
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lifted straight out of WordPress’s standard `.htaccess`. Works fine for any PHP site that needs nice URLs passed to `index.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And if your website exists on a directory off of the main server root—such as `mysite.com/realsite`— then just adjust these two lines:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Then changes to:

```
RewriteBase /realsite/
```

And this line:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Changes to:

```
RewriteRule . /realsite/index.php [L]
```